# Prove or disprove: If X has a cdf F then P(F(X) ≤ a) ≤ a. Under what condition on F will you get P(F(X) ≤ a) = a?

Tags: probability

Prove or disprove: If X has a cdf F then P(F(X) ≤ a) ≤ a. Under what condition on F will you get P(F(X) ≤ a) = a?

I think if a is negative, then the statement is false. Any hint for the equal condition?

Comment: Not sure I am following. if, say, $a=2$ then equality clearly can not hold.  So...what are you asking?

Comment: under what condition will the equality hold

Comment: Equality is impossible, for general $a$.  As I said, take $a=2$.  Or, as you said, take $a=-1$.

Comment: @Calculon $F(X)$ is definitely a random variable. $F$ is an honest-to-goodness function, $F(X)$ is that function evaluated at the random variable $X$.

Comment: @Calculon F(X) is cdf evaluate at X, so it is random, otherwise the question is trivial

Comment: @Calculon ? It is rather clear. The first part defines $F$ as the CDF of $X$ -- now $F$ is well-defined, it's a cadlag function. The second part writes $F(X)$, there is no ambiguity. Whether the question is faulty or not, *this part* is not the reason.

Comment: I think X should be uniform so that the property holds

Comment: Equality holds for $a=1$

Comment: You can consider the generalized inverse cumulative distribution function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_.28quantile_function.29). Since this inverse is nondecreasing, $F(X) \leq a \iff X \leq F^{-1}(a)$. Then your probability is $F(F^{-1}(a))$ and by definition of the generalized inverse of $F$, $F(F^{-1}(a)) \geq a$. In general the answer to your question depends on the distribution of $X$ and what $a$ actually is.

Comment: @Calculon Do you know how to show F(F^-1(a)) >=a?

Comment: @CHRIS It follows immediately from the definition of $F^{-1}$.
$$F(F^{-1}(a)) = F(\inf \{x \in \mathbb{R} : F(x) \geq a \})$$
Since $F$ is right-continuous and nondecreasing this quantity will be greater than or equal to $0$. (A drawing might help.)

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly, you introduced a new random variable, $Y = F(X)$. By definition, $Y \in [0, 1]$.

Suppose that $F(X)$ is differentiable and strictly increasing. Suppose also that $F(X)$ is invertible. Let's $f(X) = F'(X)$ be the pdf of $X$. Then the pdf of $Y$ is:

$$f_Y(Y) = \displaystyle f(\bar{X})\frac{d \bar{X}}{d Y},$$

where $Y = F(\bar{X})$ or equivalently $\bar{X} = F^{-1}(Y)$. Then:

$$f_Y(Y) = \displaystyle f(F^{-1}(Y))\frac{d F^{-1}(Y)}{d Y}.$$

Recall that:

$$\frac{d F^{-1}(Y)}{d Y} = \frac{1}{f(F^{-1}(Y))},$$

and hence $f_Y(Y) = 1 ~\forall ~Y \in [0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. This means that $Y$ is a uniformly distributed random variable in the set $[0,1]$ **whichever** is the distribution of $X$.

Finally:

$$P(F(X) \leq a) = P(Y \leq a) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $a < 0$} \\
a & \text{if $a \in [0, 1]$} \\
1 & \text{if $a > 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $$P(F(X) \leq a) \leq a$$ if $a \in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The only relevant values of $a$ are in $[0,1)$.

If $F$ is continuous, then $\{F(X)\le a\}=\{X\le G(a)\}$, where $G$ is the right-continuous inverse of $F$ defined by
$$
G(y):=\inf\{x:F(x)>y\},\qquad 0\le y<1.
$$
In this case, $P[F(X)\le a]=P[X\le G(a)]=F(G(a))=a$, the final equality resulting from the right continuity of $F$.

In general, we only have the inclusion $\{F(X)\le a\}\subset\{X\le G(a)\}$, yielding $P[F(X)\le a]\le P[X\le G(a)]=F(G(a))=a$, for $a\in[0,1)$.

**Example:** $X$ takes the values $0$ and $1$ with probabilities $1/2$ each. Let $a=1/4$. Then $P[F(X)\le 1/4]=P[F(X)=0]=0$ but $G(1/4)=1/2$ and $P[F(X)\le 1/2]=P[X\le 0]=1/2$.